# Can I tell what kind of species are in a system before jumping to it?

Tags: no-mans-sky

With the new build update, I'm trying to get a scientist.  The scientist must be a Korvax species NPC.  I've been jumping to a number of near by solar systems and keep finding Geks instead.

Can you tell what species inhabit the system before wasting a warp drive jump to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the newest update, [Atlas Rises](https://www.nomanssky.com/atlas-rises-update/), you are now able to see which is the dominant species of the Star System without having to jump multiple times to locate the one you want.

When selecting a Star System to travel to, this information is displayed on the bottom left of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to tell which species is in a solar system before jumping to it. There are a few ways to avoid wasting your warp cells though.

First, you're going to need 50-100 of each rare resource to progress through the quests, so scan the planets and pick up any resources you haven't gotten yet.  It'll save you time searching for them later.

Second, you can teleport back to your base from any space station and then teleport back to the space station, so there's no reason for you to stay close to home. Keep working on whatever goals you were previously working on (getting to the center, Atlas stones, getting resources to upgrade your stuff, exploring, finding a better home planet, etc.) and return to your base quests once you happen to find a korvax system. There's no reason to let the base quests impede your exploration.

Lastly, save right before warping, then reload your save if it's the wrong species in the system you warped to. I'd make a note of the resources you see and which species is there to save you from having to do that again every time you're sent out for something new. Also keep an eye out for planets with lots of water. You'll see why later.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are distinct "space dock" types per species. Possibly markings too.

If you don't want to waste warp cells, then use the ol' "save-try-restore-repeat" trick...

Comment: What do you mean by space docks and markings? Are these objects something you can see on the galactic map before you jump to the start system?

Comment: The star system goes like this: O/E > K/M > F/G.  Best to have top tier Warp Reactor to reach it.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Can you clarify?

Comment: It's a general indication of quality. Unfortunately, not helpful to figuring Gek/Kovax/Vykeen